# Split text in two paragraphs with twig

Tags: twig

I have rich text generated with Twig. The text is divided into two paragraphs.
How do I create a read more function/button where the first paragraph is displayed and the second will be visible on a button click?

I thought something like this:

```
  {% set paragraphs = content | split('</p>') %}
{% set firstParagraph = paragraphs | first ~ '</p>' %}
{% set secondParagraph = paragraphs[:2] ~ '</p>' %}
          <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle custom-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo"></a>
          <p>{{ firstParagraph | raw }}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
            <p>{{ secondParagraph | raw }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
              if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
                $this.text('{{ 'Read more' | t }}');      
              } else {
                $this.text('{{ 'Read less' | t }}');
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
        <a class="SeeMore2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">{{ 'Read more' | t }}</a>
```

The problem is that the second paragraph returns `array` as response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html), which is actually using [array_slice](https://secure.php.net/array_slice), which returns array.

If you want to get just one element then you can use php syntax:

```
{% set paragraphs = content | split('</p>') %}
{% set firstParagraph = paragraphs[0] ~ '</p>' %}
{% set secondParagraph = paragraphs[1] ~ '</p>' %}
```

Please read more about twig syntax and variables [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables).